# How should you pronounce the word "wolf "?

Tags: pronunciation, dialects, phonology, phonemes, allophones

If the [dictionary’s IPA for the word *wolf* is /wʊlf/](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/wolf#Pronunciation), then why do I sometimes hear people pronounce it /wolf/ instead of /wʊlf/?

Aren’t /ʊ/ and /o/ different phonemes?

Comment: They don’t, because /o/ is not a phoneme in English – or at least, when it is used to represent a phoneme, it’s the diphthong /oʊ/, which is certainly not used in _wolf_ as far as I know. [o] only occurs phonetically as allophones in certain contexts and specific dialects; e.g., as a free allophone of /ʊ/ after /w/. Most native speakers probably wouldn’t be able to tell the difference unless they specifically listened very closely for it.

Comment: I’ve never heard anyone pronounce the word as /wolf/, so you need to show evidence of this so we can understand what you’re asking. But the more important question is why do you think that everyone everywhere always pronounces all words the same way every time?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Some native speakers say words like *wolf, golf, gulf, twelfth* without any /l/ in them whatsoever. They apparently can’t have /l/ before /f/ in the coda, but that’s not too surprising as /l/ + C in the coda can be found to be weakened in many dialects and indeed languages around the world. Consider also *salmon* in most speakers of English.

Comment: @tchrist I’m absolutely certain you have heard _wolf_ pronounced with an [o] – if you listen to mainstream American media, I’d say [o] probably accounts for about 50% of the tokens in both _wolf_, _wool_, and any other words with the sequence /wʊl/. The difference in tongue movement is so slight in this sequence, though, that they can be hard to tell apart. [ɤ] is another option frequently heard (basically [o] with preemptive unrounding for the /l/).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You really think so? I'm betting that if they said /ʊ/ as [o] that I would notice them doing so; that would lead to mergers like *full–foal* or *could–code*, which is something I’ve never heard of. But if you’re going to be pulling sounds like  [ɤ] into it then I may have to think about all this some more; your ear may well be more discerning than mine for those sorts of sounds because of your Danish sensitivities, even before your formal training in phonology kicks in. A clip from American media might help me see what you mean. Got one?

Comment: It doesn't matter *if* some people pronounce it a certain way—so it's meaningless to debate the point of somebody else hearing something pronounced one way or not. (Who cares if they have or haven't—and who's to say that they haven't?). There is still no *should* when it comes to pronunciation. People don't check a dictionary before they start speaking.  They listen to how people around them talk. The only thing that matters if if you're understood.

Comment: When I listen to the IPA interpreter pronounce "/wolf/" it sounds like nothing I've ever heard before.  At best it's like a German or Russian or some such trying to pronounce the word.

Comment: @HotLicks There's an IPA pronunciator? Link?

Comment: @Mitch https://itinerarium.github.io/phoneme-synthesis/